# Virtualenv failing when creating an enviroment

Tags: python, pip

I don't know the reason, but the function mkvirtualenv is ending in the following error:

```
LEP:~ lep$ mkvirtualenv myenvironment
New python executable in myenvironment/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command /Users/lep/.virtuale...vironment           /bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
 File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
import io
 File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lep/.virtualenvs/myenvironment/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/lep/.virtualenvs/myenvironment/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
     File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/lep/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
 OSError: Command /Users/lep/.virtuale...vironment/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

It is was working before and now I am getting this error. Does someone can help me?

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Comment: Similar to this bug from conda https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Anaconda Python. You [should be](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/development/workflow/virtual_pythons.html) using [Conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) to do this not virtenv.

Try:

```
LEP:~ lep$ conda create --name myenvironment
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading to python version 2.7.9

```
conda install python=2.7.9
```

Kudos to folks here in [the GitHub conda issues section](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367)

Addendum: Thanks, [Josh Trii Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182891/josh-trii-johnston) for his comment which basically said the same thing I did... I didn't see that before.